# C++ dispatcher argument passing

Tags: c++, templates, reference, bind, dispatcher

I've a simple dispatcher struct which won't compile and honestly, I don't have any clue why.

So I created a dispatcher which you can bind a function to called update, it will invoke a static member function called invoke which dereferences the objects instance and calls the method with a simple `std::ostream` ref.

For some reason this doesn't compile, but it looks right to me.
The compiler won't give any good output :/

Thanks in advance

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <utility>

namespace trd {

  struct dispatcher {
    public:
      template<typename C, void(C::*M)(std::ostream & os) = C::update>
        static void invoke(void * instance, std::ostream & os) {
          (static_cast<C*>(instance)->*M)(os);
        }

      template<typename C, void(C::*M)(std::ostream & os) = &C::update>
        void bind(C * instance) {
          instances.push_back(std::make_pair(&invoke<C, M>, instance));
        }

      void operator () (std::ostream & os) {
        for (auto & instance : instances)
          (instance.first)(instance.second, os);
      }

    private:
      std::list<std::pair<void(*)(std::ostream & os), void *>> instances;
  };

}

struct test {
  public:
    void update(std::ostream & os) { os << "foo"; }
};

int main() {
  trd::dispatcher dp;

  test t;

  dp.bind(&t);

  dp(std::cout);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't know whether what you are doing is sound, but the only compilation error I get is because `instances` should be of type `std::list<std::pair<void(*)(void*, std::ostream & os), void *>>` the way you are using it.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher I think the duplicate does not apply. OP is not trying to store a non-static member function address in a function pointer anywhere.

Comment: @user10605163 fair enough, retracted.

Comment: Still, sounds to be that what he wants is to call non static members.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using methods and not functions, so casting the instance as void is bad practice, using C-style casts.

Instead, C++ has `std::function` and lambdas:

```
namespace trd {

  struct dispatcher {
    public:
      template<typename C, void(C::*M)(std::ostream & os) = &C::update>
        void bind(C * instance) {
          instances.push_back([=](std::ostream & os){std::invoke(M, instance, os);});
        }

      void operator () (std::ostream & os) {
        for (auto & instance : instances)
          std::invoke(instance, os);
      }

    private:
      std::list<std::function<void(std::ostream & os)>> instances;
  };
}
```

Using C++17 for `std::invoke`.

Comment: Works like a charm now! Should be using 17 more often :)

Comment: It's only invoke, which can be done by hand. The main thing is lambdas and `std::function`s ;)